# Cannot read property Array of undefined Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to fetch URLs from firebase storage and I'm just stuck with pushing them to my array so that I can use a `v-for` later to display the images.

I've searched SO and people mention binding as a solution. To give you perspective, this is my code:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // Points to the root reference
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

    // Points to 'images'
    var listRef = storageRef.child("uploads");

    // Find all the prefixes and items.
    listRef.listAll().then(function (res) {
        res.prefixes.forEach(function (folderRef) {
          console.log(folderRef);
        });
        res.items.forEach(function (itemRef) {
          const data = {
            id: storageRef.child(itemRef.fullPath).getDownloadURL(),
          };
           
        this.items = this.items.bind(this) //this is the line that I just added
          this.items.push(data); //this is the line that generates the error
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};
```

My console rèturns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`

I'm new to vue and most of what's been posted here is in angular and it doesn't really help me figure out how I can resolve my error. What should I do?
Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: I kind of disagree with the linked question on the close vote, the answer gives not a real explanation. The problem here is that you use `function()` in your snippet, function has his own function scope. Inside this scope you don't have access to objects outside your scope (`this` in your case). The (relatively) new anonymous function solves this problem. Just change all the `function ( ... )` calls to `(...) => { }` and your fine. Goodluck!

Comment: Very comprehensive explanation. Problem->cause->solution. Thank you kindly

Comment: @S.Visser sorry i reopened the question you could post your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your items array scope is in data function so you can not use this items array in other function whenever you must declared as global

Answer (score 0):

The bind should be on the `forEach` call back function.
[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
forEach(callbackfn.bind(this))
```

or

send this in the arguments :

```
forEach(callbackfn, this)
```

or use arrow functions instead of binding everywhere

```js
    listRef.listAll().then( (res)=> {
        res.prefixes.forEach( (folderRef)=> {
          console.log(folderRef);
        });
        res.items.forEach( (itemRef)=> {
          const data = {
            id: storageRef.child(itemRef.fullPath).getDownloadURL(),
          };
           
          this.items.push(data); //this is the line that generates the error
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: It's not the exactly the same question. i don't know why @BoussadjraBrahim closed it.
here you used `bind(this)` in a wrong way and no you are not should use arrow function as he answered. there is more options.